# Equivalence classes and equivalent relationship

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

We define a relation S on the set of all integers by:
   $nSk$ iff $n^2$ $=$ $k^2$ 
Decide if S is an equivalence relation. If so, what is the equivalence class of $9$?

It can be proven that S is an equivalence relation. What is the equivalence class of 9? I though it was {-81,81}, According to the key, it is {-9,9}. Am I wrong? If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sorry to say, you were wrong. First of all, no matter what the equivalence relation, the equivalence class of anything *contains that thing*. So $[9]_S$, the $S$-equivalence class of $9$, can't possibly be $\{-81, 81\}$. The $S$-equivalence class of $9$ is all things $x$ such that $9 S x$, which is to say, $[9]_S = \{x\in \mathbb{Z} \mid x^2 = 9^2\} = \{x\in \mathbb{Z} \mid x^2 = 81\} = \{-9, 9\}$.

Comment: Thank you! Apparently, I just didn't know what an equivalence class was.

Comment: Ah, yes, that would help :) I'm glad you do now.